# How to modify file content?

Tags: linux, text-processing

Ubuntu 16.04

I have some pretty large file so modifying it by hand is not possible. I'd like to change all occurences of

```
<tag1>true</tag1>
```

to

```
<tag1>false</tag1>
```

Comment: Did you means to have the closing tag say "tag1"?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes, sorry, a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
sed -e 's|<tag1>false</tag1>|<tag1>true</tag1>|g' -i file
```

although I recommend doing the edit to a copy of the file,

```
sed -e 's|<tag1>false</tag1>|<tag1>true</tag1>|g' file > newfile
```

and using `less` to check if the new contents are acceptable; i.e.

```
less newfile
```

Edited: Note the `g` modifier at the end of the pattern. It is necessary, if there can be more than one match on a line. When `g` is present, it means all matches on a line are replaced. Furthermore, instead of complete tags, you could consider just

```
sed -e 's|>false<|>true<|g' file > newfile
```

or perhaps

```
sed -e 's|>[Ff]alse<|>true<|g' file > newfile
```

which changes both `>false<` and `>False<` to `>true<`.

You can use `diff` to compare the two files, after using one of the commands above. One option is

```
diff --side-by-side file newfile | less
```

but it does not really work if the lines are very long. The *"unified diff"* format is commonly used,

```
diff -u file newfile | less
```

where lines beginning with `-` are from `file`, lines beginning with `+` from `newfile`, and lines beginning with a space are common to both.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace only the exact occurrences of

```
<tag1>true</tag1>
```

to

```
<tag1>false</tag1>
```

you can use

```
sed -r 's@<(tag1)>true</\1>@<\1>false</\1>@g' infile >outfile
```

or

```
sed -ri 's@<(tag1)>true</\1>@<\1>false</\1>@g' file
```

if you do not want to write the changed data to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to achieve with `sed` command. 
Just run:

```
sed 's/true/false/' file > newfile
```

Comment: this might incorrectly match lines that had "true" text without the surrounding tag text.

Comment: Plus, you want the `g` at the end, so that lines with more than one match have *all* the matches edited. I guess `s|>true<|>false<|g' would be a good middle ground between no tags at all, and replacing only exact matches with complete tags?